# Page Numbering Scheme

Tags: numbering, page

I am creating unit-specific guides for my students. I would like the page numbering scheme to be printed stylistically as: x-y (unit x-page y). For example:

1-1 (unit 1, page 1)

4-12 (unit 4, page 12)

5-17 (unit 5, page 17)

etc.

I am unsure of how to edit the page numbering commands. Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thesection--\thepage~(unit~\thesection, page~\thepage)}

\begin{document}
\section{Unit 1}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Unit 2}
\lipsum[7-12]
\section{Unit 3}
\lipsum[13-18]
\section{Unit 4}
\lipsum[19-24]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, reset the page counter so that it starts anew at the beginning of every section -- that is assuming your "unit" is a section, but it could also be a chapter or a subsection or any other sectioning level. It works the same with all the other sectioning levels too.

```
\counterwithin{page}{section}
```

Now, redefeine the displayed page, which is stored in the `\thepage` macro.

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{page}}
```

This will display the section as an Arabic number, a dash, and then the page as an Arabic number. It will, however, start the page at 0. If you want this, then you are done here. Otherwise, you probably want to increase the displayed value of the page, which works like this.

```
\the\numexpr\value{page}+1\relax
```

The `\the` extracts the value of the expression that follows it. `\numexpr` is used to caluclate a numeric expression, in this case the value of the `page` counter plus one. Because the numeric expression could be of any length, we now add `\relax` to tell TeX we're done with this  expression here.

Put these together and you get this command, which should get you the page numbering I assume you want.

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}-\the\numexpr\value{page}+1\relax}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

---

Edit: I assumed you wanted the page numbering to restart at every unit. If you do not want this, you just have to write

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{page}}
```

(and nothing else)